# How to remove for default images from skin folder provided by smart Gwt

Tags: smartgwt

Can we remove default images from skin folder in Smart Gwt I have tried to remove or override that image with same name but for that time it worked fine but when i compile again then all skin default images will be come

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create you own skin. Otherwise every time you compile the "default" SmartGwt skin will be reapplied. To do so read for more details and paradigms at the SmartGwt's [skinning "manual"](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html)